# FuelPHP Extended ORM Validation

Tags: validation, activerecord, orm, fuelphp

How to extend validation rules using ORM Validation (Orm\Observer_Validation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the rules to the model according to the same convention that is expected on other classes: with a `_validation_` prefixed name. The model itself will automatically be added as a callable to the Validation instance used and thus any rules it provides will be available.